# How to fix Unhandled 'error' event. Broken @import declaration of "A" while using Gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've been happily compiling using gulp.js but this afternoon I started getting this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Broken @import declaration of "A"
```

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin')
    minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('node_modules/foundation/scss/') 
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
   })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('publish/css'));
});

gulp.task('image', function(){
    gulp.src('images/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('publish/images'));
});

gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./html/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  gulp.src('publish/css/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('publish/css'));
});

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./node_modules/foundation/js/foundation/*.js','./node_modules/foundation/js/vendor/*.js'])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('publish/js'));
});

gulp.task('minify-html', function() {
  var opts = {
    conditionals: true,
    spare:true
  };

  return gulp.src('./html/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyHTML(opts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./publish/'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('node_modules/foundation/scss/', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('publish/css/*', ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch('publish/images/*', ['image']);
});

gulp.task('alpha', [ 'sass','fileinclude','minify-css','image','compress' ]);

gulp.task('omega', ['minify-html']);

gulp.task('build', ['alpha', 'omega']);

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

I've restarted, tried checking ports for conflicts and Googled this exhaustively.

Can anyone see an obvious issue that could be causing this?

edit: I should add, I'm using the Foundation framework.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your CSS files. I assume it's because you run minifyCSS and store the results in the same directory. Is there a reason why you don't run it directly after your Sass call and in a new task? Are there other CSS files, too?

Comment: and do you have somewhere an import statement where you try to import "A.css"? Maybe you can give us a Gist with your import statements throughout your files

Comment: Thank you, so very much. There's no A.css that I can see, but putting the compiled css into its own directory and _then_ minifying it and putting it in the publish directory seems to have done the trick.
I also needed to ensure I was using compass in my ruby-sass which has fixed a compliation error I was getting.
I suspect my gulpfile could be a lot more efficient, so I'll look at that next...

Answer (score 17):

The `gulp-minify-css` package was the culprit in this for me. I added this parameter to my `gulpfile.js` file and it fixed it:

```
processImport: false
```

For example:

```
.pipe(plugins.minifyCss({ keepSpecialComments: 1, processImport: false }))
```

Comment: This one helped us a lot. We had an issue with version 1.2.4 on Linux that had a problem with a proper css @import. On developer windows machines everything was fine. Turning off import processing helped us go through bamboo build that was executed on Linux server. Thanks and kudos !

Comment: This appears to not include the import at all though? Not sure how that solves the problem

Comment: I'm using Grunt and was able to solve my error of `Broken @import declaration of ".."` thanks to this